# R MLogit 'system is singular' error

Tags: r, choice-modeling, mlogit

I'm running a choice model comparing how users choose between multiple options in an app.

I have the data formatted for use with MLogit:[image]

Price and dist_rank_cat are features that vary by alternative and by choice_event.  When I run a model using just these features, the model converges and I get coefficients.  The code to run the model is:

```
choice_model <- mlogit(choice ~ price + dist_rank_cat,
                   data = choice_df,
                   chid.var = 'api_event_id',
                   alt.var = 'location_id',
                   choice = 'choice',
                   shape = "long",
                   reflevel = '3834',
                   print.level = 3)
```

Lot_dummy is a feature that varies across alternative, but does not change for each choice event (like a static product attribute).

When I add it to the model, it fails to converge and I get an error:

[image]

I don't completely understand how Mlogit wants you to specify different types of features and assume I am messing something up in the model definition that is causing this error.

Comment: Is `lot_dummy` a categorical variable? If so, is that how it is defined in R?

Comment: It's a boolean and I define it as a logical using as.logical()

Comment: I think this might hold some answers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76488/error-system-is-computationally-singular-when-running-a-glm